# Expo 49 - iOS build fails at xcodebuild without any error message

Tags: expo, fastlane, eas, nx-workspace

I'm running into an issue during my local iOS build of my expo managed iOS app inside a nx workspace. I'm using an Apple Silicon M2 Mac. I just updated my NX workspace to the latest version 17.2.8

Here is my environment:

```
  expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 14.2.1
      Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 21.5.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.21 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
      npm: 10.2.4 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.14.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 23.2, iOS 17.2, macOS 14.2, tvOS 17.2, visionOS 1.0, watchOS 10.2
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2023.1 AI-231.9392.1.2311.11076708
      Xcode: 15.2/15C500b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      @expo/metro-config: 0.10.7 => 0.10.7
      @expo/webpack-config: ^19.0.0 => 19.0.0
      babel-preset-expo: 9.5.2 => 9.5.2
      expo: 49.0.16 => 49.0.16
      metro: 0.76.8 => 0.76.8
      react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
      react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
      react-native: 0.72.6 => 0.72.6
      react-native-web: 0.19.10 => 0.19.10
    npmGlobalPackages:
      eas-cli: 6.0.0
      expo-cli: 6.3.10
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Here is the related log:

```
[INSTALL_PODS] Pod install took 11 [s] to run
[INSTALL_PODS] Integrating client project
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `MyApp.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Installing the build script for target MyApp
[INSTALL_PODS] Patching imports for file: /private/var/folders/k4/gr3vtctd1w111b6lmgcrbssc0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/59aca384-52be-4068-ae00-7fe98cb2f822/build/apps/hefe-app/node_modules/react-native-pager-view/ios/ReactNativePageView.m
[INSTALL_PODS] expo_patch_react_imports! took 0.1256 seconds to transform files.
[INSTALL_PODS] Pod installation complete! There are 71 dependencies from the Podfile and 74 total pods installed.
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `1F42667616BC45408167CAC0` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
[POST_INSTALL_HOOK] Script 'eas-build-post-install' is present in package.json, running it...
[POST_INSTALL_HOOK] > MyApp@0.0.1 eas-build-post-install
[POST_INSTALL_HOOK] > cd ../../ && node tools/scripts/eas-build-post-install.mjs . apps/MyApp
[POST_INSTALL_HOOK] Symlink created
[CONFIGURE_XCODE_PROJECT] Configuring Xcode project
[CONFIGURE_XCODE_PROJECT] Assigning provisioning profile '*[expo] com.blum.MyApp AppStore 2020-06-19T17:49:58.151Z' (Apple Team ID: FZHBG5WD5H) to target 'MyApp'
[CONFIGURE_EXPO_UPDATES] Using default release channel for 'expo-updates' (default)
[RUN_FASTLANE] Creating Gymfile
[RUN_FASTLANE] Gymfile created
[RUN_FASTLANE] Successfully loaded '/private/var/folders/k4/gr3vtctd1w111b6lmgcrbssc0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/59aca384-52be-4068-ae00-7fe98cb2f822/build/apps/MyApp/ios/Gymfile' 
[RUN_FASTLANE]
[RUN_FASTLANE] +--------------------------------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] |               Detected Values from './Gymfile'               |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-----------------------+--------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] | suppress_xcode_output | true                                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | clean                 | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | scheme                | MyApp                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | configuration         | Release                              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | export_options        | {:method=>"app-store",               |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | :provisioningProfiles=>{"com.blum.MyApp"=>"358df2c5-8579-4e25-9fda-c957664c491d"}}|
[RUN_FASTLANE] | export_xcargs         | OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain    |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | /var/folders/k4/gr3vtctd1w111b6lmgcrbssc0000gn/T/turtle-v2-c9c038c6-e143-41a8-842b-e67081afe490.keychain"  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | disable_xcpretty      | true                                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | buildlog_path         | /var/folders/k4/gr3vtctd1w111b6lmgcrbssc0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/59aca384-52be-4068-ae00-7fe98cb2f822/logs |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | output_directory      | ./build                              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-----------------------+--------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] Resolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...
[RUN_FASTLANE] $ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration Release
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ Command line invocation:
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration Release
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ User defaults from command line:
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸     IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ resolved source packages:
[RUN_FASTLANE] $ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration Release 2>&1
[RUN_FASTLANE] Command timed out after 3 seconds on try 1 of 4, trying again with a 6 second timeout...
[RUN_FASTLANE] Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"com.blum.MyApp"=>"358df2c5-8579-4e25-9fda-c957664c491d"}
[RUN_FASTLANE]
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                           Summary for gym 2.219.0                           |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] | workspace                            | ./MyApp.xcworkspace                  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | scheme                               | MyApp                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | clean                                | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | output_directory                     | ./build                              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | output_name                          | MyApp                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | configuration                        | Release                              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | silent                               | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | skip_package_ipa                     | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | skip_package_pkg                     | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | export_options.method                | app-store                            |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | export_options.provisioningProfiles  | 358df2c5-8579-4e25-9fda-c957664c491d |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | .com.blum.MyApp                       |                                     |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | export_xcargs                        | OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain    |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | /var/folders/k4/gr3vtctd1w111b6lmgc  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | rbssc0000gn/T/turtle-v2-c9c038c6-e1  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | 43-41a8-842b-e67081afe490.keychain"  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | build_path                           | /Users/maxmustermann/Library/Develope|
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | r/Xcode/Archives/2024-01-14          |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | result_bundle                        | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | buildlog_path                        | /var/folders/k4/gr3vtctd1w111b6lmgc  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | rbssc0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodej  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | s/59aca384-52be-4068-ae00-7fe98cb2f  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | 822/logs                             |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | destination                          | generic/platform=iOS                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | suppress_xcode_output                | true                                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | xcodebuild_formatter                 | xcpretty                             |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | build_timing_summary                 | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | disable_xcpretty                     | true                                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | skip_profile_detection               | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | xcodebuild_command                   | xcodebuild                           |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | skip_package_dependencies_resolutio  | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | n                                    |                                      |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | disable_package_automatic_updates    | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | use_system_scm                       | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | xcode_path                           | /Applications/Xcode.app              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/maxmustermann/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2024-01-14/MyApp\ 2024-01-14\ 17.03.18.xcarchive archive | tee /var/folders/k4/gr3vtctd1w111b6lmgcrbssc0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/59aca384-52be-4068-ae00-7fe98cb2f822/logs/MyApp-MyApp.log > /dev/null
[RUN_FASTLANE] ⚠️  Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
   To fix, go to: Xcode » MyApp/MyApp » Build Phases » 'Start Packager'
   Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script

[RUN_FASTLANE] ⚠️  Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
   To fix, go to: Xcode » MyApp/MyApp » Build Phases » 'Bundle React Native code and images'
   Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script

[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[RUN_FASTLANE] ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[RUN_FASTLANE] Exit status: 65
[RUN_FASTLANE]
[RUN_FASTLANE] +---------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] |           Build environment           |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-------------+-------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] | xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | gym_version | 2.219.0                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | sdk         | iPhoneOS17.2.sdk        |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-------------+-------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[RUN_FASTLANE] It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[RUN_FASTLANE] to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[RUN_FASTLANE] Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[RUN_FASTLANE] sure your project is set up correctly.
[RUN_FASTLANE] fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[RUN_FASTLANE] the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[RUN_FASTLANE] Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[RUN_FASTLANE] [!] Error building the application - see the log above
[RUN_FASTLANE] Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
[CLEAN_UP_CREDENTIALS] Destroying keychain - /var/folders/k4/gr3vtctd1w111b6lmgcrbssc0000gn/T/turtle-v2-c9c038c6-e143-41a8-842b-e67081afe490.keychain
[CLEAN_UP_CREDENTIALS] Removing provisioning profile

Build failed
The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
npx exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Normally the log provides some valuable information. But in this case there is no information. And because my app is expo managed, I don't have a Xcode project where I could check the logs.

The build works fine on my Intel based Mac mini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following two things

1. Go to `eas credentials` and recreate your provisioning and distribution certificates
2. Go to App Store Connect to see whether there are any agreements that the Account Owner has to agree to.

Comment: Recreate the provisioning and distribution certificates did the job. I had to delete all other certificates from my expo account. Now it's working fine. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll to the bottom of the screen you may be able to find more details in the XCode logs:

[image]

Comment: I'm doing local builds. Where can I find the Logs there?

Comment: I'm not certain as I only started with local builds today. You can check this link but personally I didn't find logs where it claimed they'd be: https://betterprogramming.pub/lets-parse-xcode-logs-dea4e5fb1de4